# MySQL query two different colums with same foreign table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling with an sql query.

I do need to know the network, cidr, vrfold (id, name and backbone) and vrfnew (id, name and backbone).

Maybe someone can help.

```
networks
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| network         | varbinary(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cidr            | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| vrfnew_id       | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| vrfold_id       | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| vlan            | varchar(45)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

vrfs
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| backbones_id | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

backbones
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: Are all those three table the input or one of them is the expected output? Explain more what you have and what you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.network, 
       A.cidr, 
       A.vrfold_id, 
       B.name as vrfold_name, 
       C.name as vrfold_backbone_name, 
       A.vrfnew_id, 
       D.name as vrfnew_name, 
       E.name as vrfnew_backbone_name
FROM networks A
JOIN vrfs B on A.vrfold_id = B.id
JOIN backbones C on B.backbones_id = C.id
JOIN vrfs D on A.vrfnew_id = D.id
JOIN backbones E on D.backbones_id = E.id
```

Comment: Thx you made my day. ;) Did not think about joins in this case.